# Highlight exact phrase with haystack/elasticsearch in Django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

My web app uses Django Haystack with Elasticsearch as the search engine.

My `SearchForm` child class filters for exact search (`content__exact` parameter) if the search query contains a token with quotes.

```
class NepSearchForm(SearchForm):

# ...

    def search(self):
        if not self.is_valid():
            return self.no_query_found()

        if not self.cleaned_data.get('q'):
            return self.no_query_found()

        sqs = self._parse_query(self.cleaned_data['q'])

        if self.load_all:
            sqs = sqs.load_all()

        return sqs

    def no_query_found(self):
        return self.searchqueryset.all()

    def _parse_query(self, query):
        """
        Parse query treating modifiers 'AND', 'OR', 'NOT' to make what they're
        supposed to.
        :param query: query entered in search input box in form
        :param sqs: SearchQuerySet until now
        :return: SearchQuerySet object
        """
        words = iter(shlex.split(query))
        result = self.searchqueryset

        for word in words:
            try:
                if word == 'AND':
                    result = result.filter_and(content=words.__next__())
                elif word == 'OR':
                    # TODO: fail when changing order of the words. See
                    # TODO: functional test:
                    # TODO: test_search_with_OR_modifier_returns_correct_objects
                    result = result.filter_or(content=words.__next__())
                elif word == 'NOT':
                    result = result.exclude(content=words.__next__())
                # if "word" is compounded of more than one non blank word the
                # term is inside quotes
                elif len(word.split()) > 1:
                    result = result.filter(content__exact=word)
                else:
                    result = result.filter(content=word)
            except StopIteration:
                return result

        return result
```

I'm using the Django template tag `{% highlight %}` to highlight the terms searched in my app, like in:

```
{% highlight result.object.<field> with query %}
```

What I'm seeing is that, when I make a search with quotes with more than one word, separated by spaces, e.g `"História de fratura"`, the search results appears with only the token `"de"` highlighted. So it seems that Highlighter class does not treat terms with quotes as single tokens to mark them highlighted in search results.

What can I do to highlight the query with a whole term inside quotes in search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your own [highlighter](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/highlighting.html#highlighter) class as documentation states if default highlighter implementation doesn't work for you.